# How to calculate the rotated coordinates of a line in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have rotated a line based using Transform Group in UWP. Once after rotation I need to get the new bounds of line using the transform matrix value .Whether it is possible to get the current points of line using the matrix value? Can anyone help me out on this ?

```
RotateTransform rotate = new RotateTransform();
rotate.Angle = -angle;    
var translate = new TranslateTransform
{
X = offset,
Y = offset                                   
 };                                       
var group = new TransformGroup
{
 Children = { (Transform)translate.Inverse, rotate,translate }
};
line.RenderTransform = group;

var  matrix = ((line.RenderTransform as TransformGroup).Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know and access the `Parent` of the `Line`, then I think you can do this:

```
var line_bound = line.TransformToVisual(parent).TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, Math.Abs(line.X2 - line.X1), Math.Abs(line.Y2 - line.Y1)));
```

Here the *parent* may be a `Grid` or a `Canvas` that you attach the `line` to.

Read more about `TransformBounds(Rect)` Method  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.generaltransform.transformbounds#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_GeneralTransform_TransformBounds_Windows_Foundation_Rect_).